# List and tables in a scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to create a list (JList) and next to it - tables.
What I could only do is create a useless list and nothing further.
I really don't know what to do.. but the situation I am in..
I can freely say it's near of "life and death" importance.

Comment: Sorry but we cannot write programs instead of you. We only can help to find your mistakes or reccomend some usefull links.

Comment: I know, but theoritically.. fixing my mistake WILL be actually you writing a program for me. :( I am not happy too, but that's how it stands. It is exactly THAT bad. In Bulgaria we are not really rich, but I spent all my money and now I am about to loose them, because of a sheer UNluck of me having to do this in Java.

Comment: 1) Please clarify what function the list should have and what the tables are for, it's not very clear what you're asking (atleast to me) 2) Post what you've tried ([mcve])